# XSL node selection by attribute value

Tags: variables, xslt, attributes, comparison, value-of

I am having some problem with the following xsl command:

```
<xsl:value-of select="./a/b/c[@code='$codeVal']" />
```

codeVal is a variable which holds the value of another attribute from some other section of the XML.
The above statement does not work. Debugging shows that $codeVal variable does contain a valid/correct value

However, if I hardcode values then everything just works fine

for example, the following statements work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="./a/b/c[@code='one']" />
<xsl:value-of select="./a/b/c[@code='two']" />
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with the statement above?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I should be referencing variables without quotes.

Instead of $codeVal in single quotes:

```
xsl:value-of select="./a/b/c[@code='$codeVal']" />
```

I should have written the statement in the following way:

```
xsl:value-of select="./a/b/c[@code=$codeVal]" />
```